# Can I recover from this git error? "fatal: Duplicated ref, and SHA1s don't match: refs/heads/BranchName"

Tags: git, fatal-error

```
fatal: Duplicated ref, and SHA1s don't match: refs/heads/BranchName
```

I should note that I'm on Ubuntu Lucid, which is relevant for some of the file system comments.

I got this error right after doing a git pull origin master while locally on master. Pretty usual thing to do. The pull itself seemed to work, I saw the list of all the files being pulled down. But nothing after that has.

I looked at some of the other answers on SO, but they all involve running a git command. At this point I can't run any git command, fsck included. I just get the same message. I was suggested that I delete .git/refs/heads/BranchName but it didn't work. Though I saw an interesting thing: The only thing in /refs/heads was the bad branch, with a ? at the end (probably some unknown character). No other branches listed there.

I've had issues in the past where git fsck would fail, and then it magically was ok again. Sounds a lot like HD failure, but smartctl's long test told me nothing bad when that happened before. I tried the quick status check just now and it seems to be fine still.

Not a huge deal, I can re-clone. I didn't lose much. But it would be nice to get it back, and also to have this here for others who get the same problem.

Thanks.

Comment: can you plz list files in .git/refs/heads/ and ouput their content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to reproduce the problem: the file `.git/packed-refs` has two entries for `refs/heads/BranchName` and they have different SHAs, git doen't know which one is the correct and leaves your with that fatal error.

Delete one of them to resolve the conflict, your `BranchName` branch may end up pointing to a nonexistent commit, but you'll be able to run git commands again.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I actually don't need that particular branch so it's no loss.

Comment: Very interesting. What caused this problem? Was it really an HD failure?